# tar query:How to speedup tar for many files in .tgz file

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have around thousands(approx say 20000) of files in sample.tgz which when I am doing decompression using tar-xf is taking more than 5 minutes.I want to speed it up to within a minute.The approach which I am thinking of is getting all the names of files in the .tgz file using -T option and then running tar in parallel in batches of say 500 file names.

Could somebody suggest a better approach?Please note that I have to use tar only here and not any other utilities like pigz and parallel etc.

Similarly if anyone can suggest the approach to compress it faster,that would also be helpful.

Also not that there is no .tgz file inside my sample.tgz file.

Comment: How large is sample.tgz?

Comment: Get a faster hard disk, or an SSD.

Comment: @Cyrus : Its around 8MB

Comment: What filesystem are you extracting that to?

Answer (score 1):

Tarballs are linear archives (mimicing the media they are named after; Tape ARchive) and so don't parallelize well until decompressed. Speeding up the decompression operation by using an algorithm such as [LZ4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_%28compression_algorithm%29) will help some, but if you're stuck with a gzipped tarball then the only chance you'll have of speeding it up is to use pigz instead of gzip to decompress it to a .tar file and then extract the files from there.